# GAE - NDB: Performance of JsonProperty vs StructuredProperty?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Has anyone compared serialisation/deserialisation performance of JsonProperty versus StructuredProperty for "repeated" objects (lists)?

What should I choose if primary goal is to minimise deserialisation time and 2nd is to minimise storage space?

Comment: I'm also seeing what seems like pretty slow performance with large StructuredProperty repeated lists.  Any update on improving performance?  Did you move to a different approach?

Comment: I switched to Go language and use JSON as string props with ffjson library as serializer. Blazing fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found `StructuredProperty` to be very slow.  It seems to do a lot of checking with every read and write.  I have since moved to `JsonProperty` and it is much faster.  I think it takes less storage space, too.